# k-shortest paths with iso-timing constraint

Tags: shortest-path

I would like to solve the $k$ shortest paths on a directed graph  $\mathcal{G}= (\mathcal{V},\mathcal{A})$ :
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\underset{\{x_{ij}\}}{\text{argmin}}\biggl\{\sum_{(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}}a_{ij}x_{ij}\biggr\}
\end{equation}
in which $a_{ij}$ is a non negative scalar quantifying the cost of arc $(i,j)$, $x_{ij}\in\{1,0\}$
whether the arc $(i,j)$ is in the path or not and, with constraints :
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
\forall i\in\mathcal{V}\;,\quad y_{i}= \sum_{j\,/\,(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}}x_{ij} - \sum_{j\,/\,(j,i)\in\mathcal{A}}x_{ji} =
\begin{cases}
  1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=s  \\
  -1 &,\,\text{if}\; i=t \\
  0 &,\,\text{if}\; i\notin \{s,t\}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $s$ and $t$ are respectively the starting and terminal nodes.

Say the cost $a_{ij}$ of arc $(i,j)$ encodes the time of travel from node $i$ to $j$.

How can I account for the constraint that I would like the k-shortest path to have the equal time of travel from source to terminal nodes ?

My intuition is that I would need to find "dissimilar" paths, because if I select the shortest path and then the second shortest one, they obviously would not arrive in the same time at terminal node (assuming they started together).

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is.  What if the k shortest paths don't all have equal costs?  What do you want then?  It is not clear what paths you want to be output.  Do you want the smallest cost $c$ such that there exist k paths of cost $c$?  Do you want the shortest path, and up to $k-1$ other paths of the same cost?  Something else?  Please [edit] your question to specify the problem more clearly.  The problem is not solvable without a clear problem specification.